# Function using While True not working as expected. Asks for input Twice

Tags: python

The purpose of this function is to check the input of the user, determine if its in the list, and, if not, tells the user to ''Select one of the given options''.

*The issue with it is that it asks me for input twice*. When I select option ''Approach exit door'' it loops again and asks for input, when I enter the same option again thats when I get the result (which leads to dead() function not copied here to keep this short). Tried several things, like adding a condition that closes the loop and tries to make the While False so it stops, but it didnt work. Also, thanks to user khelwood who provided me with this alternative and simplified my program.

**too long didnt read? Loop asks for input twice, cant fix it.**

Heres the code.

```
s2option_list =['Approach exit door', 'Check for vital signs']

def sget_choice(s2option_list):
    while True:
        print s2option_list
        choice = raw_input('> ')
        for i, opt in enumerate(s2option_list):
            if opt in choice:
                 return i
            else:
                print "You need to select one of the given options."

def scenario2(response):
    print response
    print "Conversation"
    print "Conversation"
    print "Conversation"

    sget_choice(s2option_list)

    if sget_choice(s2option_list)==0:
        dead("Conversation")              
    else:
        print "Conversation"

        sget_choice2(s2option_list2)
```

Comment: Also, you call `sget_choice` two times in `scenario2`. Once before and one inside of the `if` statement.

Comment: The sget_choice at the end is supposed to call another function with the same aim. So, Padraic, I am fairly new at this so I barely understand it. You mean that if I add a return 0 in scenario2 it will fix the problem?

Comment: @LittleFoot, I added an answer, I am not 100 percent on the `== 0` though, do you only accept one option?

Comment: Well, as far as I know its supposed to point to the first option in the list. Else would be second option and then it will print/call another function.

Comment: ah ok scratch that, I missed the 2 I thought you called `sget_choice` again, your problem was you were calling the function twice, you need to just call once and store the return value and compare that or just use  `if sget_choice(s2option_list)==0` once and forget the previous call

Comment: Maybe you want `if choice in opt:`. That way you wouldn't have to type the whole phrase in for a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def scenario2(response):
    print response
    print "Conversation"
    print "Conversation"
    print "Conversation"    
    res = sget_choice(s2option_list) # call it once save return value in a variable   
    if res == 0: # now you are checking the value from the previous call not calling again
        dead("Conversation")              
    else:
        print "Conversation"   
        sget_choice2(s2option_list2)
```

Comment: This fixed the function and pretty much everything. Thanks you people made my night.

Comment: No prob, you might consider giving the user a menu to pick from, might make life easier